# Finding $a$ such that $y=|\sin x|$ and $y=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}{|x|} + a$ are tangent to each other

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

I am trying to solve the given problem

> If $$|\sin x|= \frac{\sqrt3}{2}{|x|}+a$$
> Find $a$ for which no solution exists for $x$.

To solve, I begin by roughly graphing $y=|\sin x|$ and $y=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}{|x|} + a$

I need a value of $a$ for which these curves are tangent to each other. However, I can't figure out how to do so.

Using a graphing calculator, I get a value close to $0.04$, but I need the exact value.

Comment: What do you mean by "tangent to each other"? And how would doing that show no solutions exist?

Comment: @coffeemath I mean that the line $y=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}|x|+a$ would touch the curve $y=|sinx|$. This will give a value for $a$, say $a_1$. For $a>a_1$ there would be no solution.

Comment: Yeeter: Yes I now see what you mean. the answer below by user Ingix proceeds your way, and gives a few hints to help you finish the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since both sides if the equation don't change when subsituting $-x$ for $x$, the graphs of those two functions are symmetrical about the $y$-axis, so we can restrict ourselves to one side of it, and choose $x\ge0$. What happens at $x=0$, is easy to see, I assume you already figured that out.

Now at $x>0$ the function $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt3}2|x|+a$ is simply $\frac{\sqrt3}2x+a$, which is a line with a **constant** slope/derivative which is independent of $a$. Can you find that slope? Can you find a point on $g(x)=|\sin x|$ where the tangent has the same slope? Can you continue from here?

Comment: This worked, For some reason I did not think of looking for a point which gave the same slope as the sine curve. Thank you!